# Can you embed markdown in OpenAPI?

Tags: yaml, openapi, jsonpointer

I presently have

```yaml
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: My API
  version:
    $ref: package.json#/version
  description: |
    practically the same content as README.md
```

Is there a way with JSON Pointers to embed text rather than JSON object?  Something along the lines of

```yaml
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title: My API
  version:
    $ref: package.json#/version
  description: |
    $ref: README.md
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually I was close and it did work.  I didn't expect it to

```yaml
openapi: 3.1.0
info:
  title:
    $ref: package.json#/description
  version:
    $ref: package.json#/version
  description:
    $ref: README.md
```

So now I basically avoided repeating myself for the title, version and the description.